# Notification bar overlapping with content

Tags: html, css

I'm using the code from this page to show a notification bar at the top of my website:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/show-n-hide-notification-bar/

You can view their demo of it here:  http://demo.hongkiat.com/show-n-hide-notification-bar/

The problem is that the notification bar is overlapping my logo and I want it to actually push it down instead.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div class="demo-wrapper">
    <div class="notification-bar">
        <input id="hide" type="radio" name="bar" value="hide">
        <input id="show" type="radio" name="bar" value="show" checked="checked">

        <label for="hide">hide</label>
        <label for="show">show</label>

        <div class="notification-text">Hello World, you can hide this notification by clicking the close button.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What do I need to change for it to push everything down instead of overlapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried giving your logo a "position:relative;" and "z-index:99999;" for example?